# How I can retrieve a migration's class name so I can replace it with my own autogenerated code?

Tags: php, laravel, replace, laravel-5.8

I laravel I created the following db migration that contains the following content usin `php artisan make:migration`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MyCustomMigration extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
    }
}
```

And I want to retrieve the class name from the migration above and replace it with custom contents from a template php file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class ^CLASS_NAME^ extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       $sql=<<<'SQL'

'SQL'

      DB::statement($sql);
    }
}
```

In the template above I want to replace the `^CLASS_NAME^` with `MyCustomMigration` in order to make custom migrations via laravel's artisan commands based upon migration templates. Do you know how I can do that?

What I want is to have multiple "types" of migration that each type will contain specified code. I do not want to completely replace the migration generation but to create a specific type of migration when I need it.

Comment: Class names are usually fixed. There is probably a better solution for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you trying to edit/change the way default migrations are created in Laravel when using `php artisan make:migration`?

Comment: Missing the [tag:laravel] tag ?

Comment: @brombeer I am trying to manipulate the migration after `php artisan make:migration` is called. What I am thinking is to create the migration as laravel does and then use a template to ovewrite its contents with my own.